# Calling method getFocusAreas() causes java.lang.NumberFormatException on HTC ONE

Tags: android

While working with camera API I came across a problem on a device HTC ONE. I hace checked this on LG G2 and it went through without an error.
I have tracked down the problem down to a single line:

```
List<Camera.Area> areas = camera.getParameters().getFocusAreas();
```

Method getParameters() works by it self. So the problem is in getFocusArea().
This a snippet from LogCat.

```
07-24 18:29:13.716 W/ActivityMain(28952): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: " 0"
07-24 18:29:13.716 W/ActivityMain(28952):   at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
07-24 18:29:13.716 W/ActivityMain(28952):   at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
07-24 18:29:13.716 W/ActivityMain(28952):   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
07-24 18:29:13.716 W/ActivityMain(28952):   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
07-24 18:29:13.716 W/ActivityMain(28952):   at android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.splitInt(Camera.java:4321)
07-24 18:29:13.716 W/ActivityMain(28952):   at android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.splitArea(Camera.java:4428)
07-24 18:29:13.716 W/ActivityMain(28952):   at android.hardware.Camera$Parameters.getFocusAreas(Camera.java:4088)
```

This is device info.

```
build.board: APQ8064
build.bootloader: 1.57.0000
build.brand: htc
build.cpu_abi: armeabi-v7a
build.cpu_abi2: armeabi
build.device: m7
build.display: KOT49H release-keys
build.fingerprint: htc/htc_europe/m7:4.4.2/KOT49H/334166.10:user/release-keys
build.hardware: m7
build.host: abm019
build.id: KOT49H
build.manufacturer: HTC
build.model: HTC One
build.product: htc_europe
build.radio: unknown
build.serial: FA35WW934521
build.tags: release-keys
build.time: 1399302943000
build.type: user
build.user: buildteam
version.codename: REL
version.incremental: 334166.10
version.release: 4.4.2
version.sdk_int: 19
```

So, can anybody explain why it comes to this and if there is a workaround?

Comment: You got it explained in your exception: `Invalid int: " 0"`. Get rid of that space.

Comment: @Marcin Thank you for your bright insight. These faulty string is not dependent on me but on inner workings of API. I know the problem is that string. Please read the question and do not post (or downvote) if you do not know what you are writing about.

Comment: The answer is `Get rid of that space`. I got record of HTC devices doing oddities with number formats here and there (like using `,` instead of `.` while all other devices used `.` hence crashing for the same reason due to format mismatch. So `get rid of the space` :)

Comment: How? The exception is inside method getFocusAreas(). It is an API call. I did not write it. Neither did I put any strings anywhere.

Comment: Can confirm same problem with getMeteringAreas().

Comment: ratr you can flatten the Camera.Parameters or extract directly the focus-areas key as a String, is what Marcin means.

Answer (score 3):

Seems this is a bug in the API happening only in some devices.
This only happens if no areas have been submitted yet by calling **setFocusAreas()**

The workaround is simple. Call at least one time **setFocusAreas**(). Probably you want to do this in some type of setup / initialization function, or to keep a flag to track if you called this function at least one time.

See the [this link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61101) for more information about the bug.